# Android login and redirect

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get some data from a webpage that needs login in a page. I could do with htmlunit but gave me problems import these libraries on Android. So I am trying to do it with apache http client.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://inside.cineca.it/cgi-bin/uinside/marcature.pl");
BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", "user");
BasicNameValuePair passwordBasicNameValuePAir = new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", "pass");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairList.add(usernameBasicNameValuePair);
nameValuePairList.add(passwordBasicNameValuePAir);
UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
```

But is giving me error. I am affraid i should manage the redirect but i don't know how. I would be happy if someone could give me some advice. 
Best regards

Comment: Give the error log please.

Answer (score 0):

You're performing an `http POST` to a login page. Maybe the server that serves you back the login page doesn't know to handle the post. Anyway, I am sure your intention is to perform the login actually. You need to figure out what is the server API where you should post the credentials and process the result. Performing a quick investigation with Chrome Network profiler, the login API for above link actually resides at: `https://idp-is.cineca.it/idp/Authn/Multilogin`. That is the URL that you should be using and there is where you need to POST.

Also, make sure the request you're making is done on a non-UI thread as this is a common mistake done by beginners.

Comment: So I should change the HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://inside.cineca.it/cgi-bin/uinside/marcature.pl"); with HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://idp-is.cineca.it/idp/Authn/Multilogin"); I am a little lost and if you would have some example would be great!

Comment: No way...in this way it's not printing System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity())); Could you explain or said me more or less what I should do?